# Non breaking whitespace in python

Tags: python

Why don't python remove non breaking whitespace on `.strip(' ')` but `.split(' ')` splits on
the character?

Comment: I'd like to see some code. But the doc says "split() ... Return a copy of the string with the **leading** and **trailing** characters removed. "

Comment: ... you mean `strip()` Kai ... strip trims leading and trailing characters (spaces in default).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly these functions perform two different tasks:

```
'      foo    bar    '.split() is ['foo','bar']
#a list of substrings without any white space (Note the default is the look for whitespace - see below)
'      foo    bar    '.strip() is 'foo    bar'
#the string without the beginning and end whitespace
```

.

When using `strip(' ')` only **spaces** at the beginning and end are removed, although very similar to `strip()` it's not quite the same, for example with tab `\t` which is whitespace but isn't a space:

```
'   \t   foo   bar  '. strip()    is 'foo   bar'
'   \t   foo   bar  '. strip(' ') is '\t   foo   bar'
```

When using `split(' ')` it "splits" the string into a list against **each** space, compared to `split()` splitting the string into a list against **each** "whitespace". Consider `'foo  bar'` (with two spaces between foo and bar).

```
'foo  bar'.split()    is ['foo', 'bar']
#Two spaces count as only one "whitespace"
'foo  bar'.split(' ') is ['foo', '', 'bar']
#Two spaces split the list into THREE (seperating an empty string)
```

*The subtlety being that two spaces, or several spaces and tabs, are counted as "**one** whitespace".*

Comment: The OP's question is about `split(' ')`, not `split()`, and talks about non-breaking whitespace which you don't address at all.

Comment: "The default argument for both strip and split is a space": This isn't right.  Compare `"a  b".split()` and `"a  b".split(" ")` [there are two spaces between "a" and "b" there], or `"a\tb".split(" ")` vs `"a\tb".split()`.

Comment: Incidentally, your first output isn't right either.  It will give `['', '', '', '', '', '', 'foo', '', '', '', 'bar', '', '', '', '']`.

Comment: @DSM I have updated answer to reflect this, thanks for letting me know (and enabling me to understand more about strip and split) :)